# Google Cloud Storage File System, Python Package Error: AttributeError: 'GCSFile' object has no attribute 'gcsfs'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-3.7, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a python code which will download and stream chunks of data from source URL to destination cloud storage blob.
It is working fine in standalone pc, local function and so on.
But when i try same with GCP Cloud RUN it is throwing weird error.

```
AttributeError: 'GCSFile' object has no attribute 'gcsfs'
```

Complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1683, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1661, in close
    self.flush(force=True)
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1527, in flush
    self._initiate_upload()
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 1443, in _initiate_upload
    self.gcsfs.loop,
AttributeError: 'GCSFile' object has no attribute 'gcsfs'
```

It consumed my week, any help or direction is highly appriciated, thanks in advance.

The actual code which has been used:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import gcsfs
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/urltogcs')
def urltogcs():
    try:
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "secret.json"
        gcp_file_system = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='<project_id>')
        session = requests.Session()
        url = request.args.get('source', 'temp')
        blob_path = request.args.get('destination', 'temp')
        with session.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with gcp_file_system.open(blob_path, 'wb') as f_obj:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
                    f_obj.write(chunk)
        return f'Successfully downloaded from {url} to {blob_path} :)'
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failure")
        print(e)
        return f'download failed for  {url} :('


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i have just added the code into actual question.

Comment: You should not `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="secret.json"`. `gcsfs` appears to use Application Default Credentials (see [Credentials](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials)) and so this step is unncessary and saves you putting Service Account secrets in deployment artifacts (which is insecure). The code will use the Cloud Run service's (default) identity so ensure you grant it permissions to GCS.

Comment: When you run the code locally (after removing that statement), you may `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/secret.json` and then run your code and Application Default Credentials will authenticate your code that way too.

Comment: Totally agree with @DazWilkin. Avoid using explicit secret. Prefer environment variable locally, and nothing in the Cloud (you have the metadata server that provide credential to library under the hood). You can also avoid using key file by doing a `gcloud auth application-default login`, to use your credential instead. Clean up your code and it should be clearer, simpler, and easier to debug.

Comment: What is the name of the directory where this code is located? Do you have a subdirectory with a name that conflicts?

Comment: @JohnHanley its under app, /home/<user>/app/<codebase>

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your code (with the proposed changes) works for me:

`main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import gcsfs
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

project = os.getenv("PROJECT")
port = os.getenv("PORT", 8080)

@app.route('/urltogcs')
def urltogcs():
    try:
        gcp_file_system = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=project)
        session = requests.Session()
        url = request.args.get('source', 'temp')
        blob_path = request.args.get('destination', 'temp')
        with session.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with gcp_file_system.open(blob_path, 'wb') as f_obj:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
                    f_obj.write(chunk)
        return f'Successfully downloaded from {url} to {blob_path} :)'
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failure")
        print(e)
        return f'download failed for  {url}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(port))
```

Note: The code requires `project` from the environment which isn't ideal. It would be better if `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem` didn't require `project`. Alternatively `project` could be obtained from Google's metadata service. For convenience (!), I'm setting it using the environment.

`requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==2.2.2
gcsfs==2022.7.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Bash script:

```bash
BILLING="[YOUR-BILLING]"
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT]"
REGION="[YOUR-REGION]"
BUCKET="[YOUR-BUCKET]"

# Create Project
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

# Associate with Billing Account
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enabled services
SERVICES=(
  "artifactregistry"
  "cloudbuild"
  "run"
)
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES[@]}
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Create Bucket
gsutil mb -p ${PROJECT} gs://${BUCKET}

# Service Account
ACCOUNT=tester
EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Service Account key
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Ensure Service Account can write to storage
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--role=roles/storage.admin \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL}

# Only needed for local testing
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

# Deploy Cloud Run service
# Run service as Service Account
NAME="urltogcs"
gcloud run deploy ${NAME} \
--source=${PWD}  \
--set-env-vars=PROJECT=${PROJECT} \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--service-account=${EMAIL} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Grab the Cloud Run service's endpoint
ENDPOINT=$(gcloud run services describe ${NAME} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(status.url)")

# Cloud Run service requires auth
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-identity-token)

# This page
SRC="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73393808/"

# Generate a GCS Object name by epoch
DST="gs://${BUCKET}/$(date +%s)"

curl \
--silent \
--get \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--data-urlencode "source=${SRC}" \
--data-urlencode "destination=${DST}" \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
--output /dev/null \
${ENDPOINT}/urltogcs
```

Yields OK:

```
200
```

And:

```bash
gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}

gs://${BUCKET}/1660780270
```

Comment: Really appriciate the standards, but am still unable to understand and/or isolate the issue. For me its still same error.

Comment: Here's my challenge. Because the above example works for me, I don't see your errors and so I'm unable to help you resolve them. Have you followed the instruction in this answer (potentially using a new project)?

Comment: coming again, its weird, with normal python console gcsfilesystem works fine, but with flask app its like for me always giving error , [2022-09-01 14:22:20,299: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 'GCSFile' object has no attribute 'gcsfs'.. will check again on this, like whats the core problem.